# Json.NET converting from json to xml

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, json.net

I have tried to use the Json.Convert method to get my content into xml however my html content is encoded (by json.net)

**Note:** I dont have access to the system.web dll

```
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
```

My class:

```
public class TemplateContent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string VersionNumber { get; set; }
    public string CoverPage { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

I want the prop CoverPage - to be in straight up html without encodings

My code:
first convert to json... (content is the above object)

```
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
        return json;
```

then transform to xml

```
        var myXmlNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "Template");
```

Can this bit of the code `JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode` - be forced to decode the content? or leave the content as it is when converting into xml?

```
<Template>
  <ID>14</ID>
  <Name>name of report</Name>
  <VersionNumber>1.0</VersionNumber>
  <CoverPage>






  &lt;br /&gt;
  &lt;br /&gt;
  &lt;h3 style="text-align: center;"&gt;
    &lt;br class="GENTICS_ephemera" /&gt;
  &lt;/h3&gt;
  &lt;h3 style="text-align: center;"&gt;
    &lt;br class="GENTICS_ephemera" /&gt;
  &lt;/h3&gt;
  &lt;h3 style="text-align: center;"&gt;Property Valuation Report&lt;/h3&gt;     

        </CoverPage>
  <Body>




  &lt;h4 style="text-align: center;"&gt;Property Valuation Report&lt;/h4&gt;
  &lt;p&gt;
  &lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p&gt;
  &lt;/p&gt;</Body>
</Template>
```

[image]

Comment: @Harron, your xml is valid and if you parse it with an xml parser(or deserialize to a class) you'll get correct(decoded) values.

Comment: @L.B - how would I do that? (sorry I am a newbie)

Comment: @L.B - Yes, my xml is valid so I know half the job is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your xml is valid and if you parse it with an xml parser(or deserialize to a class) you'll get correct(decoded) values. For example,

```
string xmlx = @"
<Template>
  <ID>14</ID>
  <Name>name of report</Name>
  <VersionNumber>1.0</VersionNumber>
  <CoverPage>
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;h3 style=""text-align: center;""&gt;
&lt;br class=""GENTICS_ephemera"" /&gt;
&lt;/h3&gt;
&lt;h3 style=""text-align: center;""&gt;
&lt;br class=""GENTICS_ephemera"" /&gt;
&lt;/h3&gt;
&lt;h3 style=""text-align: center;""&gt;Property Valuation Report&lt;/h3&gt;  
  </CoverPage>
</Template>";

XElement xelem = XElement.Load(new StringReader(xmlx));
string xmlvalue = xelem.Descendants("CoverPage").First().Value;
```

will return

```
<br />
<br />
<h3 style="text-align: center;">
<br class="GENTICS_ephemera" />
</h3>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">
<br class="GENTICS_ephemera" />
</h3>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Property Valuation Report</h3>
```

So answer to `or leave the content as it is when converting into xml?` is  **Yes**

Comment: Strange... just tried it and it does not work...  **&lt;br /&gt;** will not work

Comment: I have ran your tests and it does seem to work *when* you actually iterate over the tag, however I am using xslt to transform the document from the above ancoded into xsl fo... my xslt document is not picking this up, should I open another question?

Comment: @Haroon, I tested above code before I posted. It **does** work. Just copy-paste it to some project and try.

Comment: Sorry- I meant to say when iterating over the document **whilst** doing my xslt transform the tags are not being picked up - because I check if something is li - then do something.

Comment: Also: when doing a console.writeline on your example you get the encoded values

Comment: I added `Console.WriteLine(xmlvalue);` to my code and I see `xmlvalue` as decoded (try it without  xslt transformation)

Comment: is that in .net 4.0 as I have .net 3.5 - should not make any difference though as I copied and pasted your code into my test project *very* strange

Comment: I dont get an error I said I see the encoded values, as per my image (see above)

Comment: @Haroon  Output `xmlvalue` not `xelem`. sorry for bad names

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content.Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", "<"));
return json;
```

Comment: dont have access to the system.web - even if i did, json.net is destroying it as I stated in my question so this wont work

Comment: Ok, try a string replace. Modified answer to reflect. Also, if that gets more complex, say... needing to decode Entities, you may just want to write a function, or add `using System.Web` to your class and then use the built-in functions.